# Plotting a graph between 2 variables using pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I need to plot a graph between various attributes of my dataset ans all I know as per my current knowledge is histogram, and in that I can take only one variable.

I tried with this simple code:

```
sn.catplot(x="CDR", y="Age", hue="M/F", data=df);
plt.title('Distribution of Age by CDR rate')
```

[This is the Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ5hZ.png)

CDR is Clinical Dementia Rating.
I do have code in R language ,they have 1st grouped them all and then plotted the graph but I found that even more complecated so I decided to go with this way.

[This is the type of graph I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C78dn.png)

I am clueless about this error.
I tried df.CDR, df.age, df.M/F and that is giving error due to name "M/F".

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'M'

I tried changing name in dataset but that's giving even more errors.

[If R code is required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02x9n.png)

Help!!!!
[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyhlf.png)

Comment: Please do not post code/data/error messages as images on SO, post it directly here on SO as text. See also: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: As for the error, maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32908315

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0):

In Python, use seaborn.violinplot

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

Full example below (from seaborn doc):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [87, 88, 89, 60, 55, 58, 59],
                   ["M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M"]]).T
df.columns = ["CDR", "Age", "M/F"]

df = df.astype({"CDR": "float64", "Age": "int64"}) # Update type

sns.violinplot(x="CDR", y="Age", hue="M/F", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: same error. Could not interpret input 'CDR'

Comment: Does your column 'CDR' really exist in your dataframe ?

Please post a df.head() output.

Comment: It works for me, I updated by answser with data like yours. Please check that your data type are correct ("float64" or "int64" for "CDR" and "Age")